# How to project a new vector onto PCA space?

Tags: r, pca

After performing principal component analysis (PCA), I want to project a new vector onto PCA space (i.e. find its coordinates in the PCA coordinate system).

I have calculated PCA in R language using `prcomp`. Now I should be able to multiply my vector by the PCA rotation matrix. Should principal components in this matrix be arranged in rows or columns?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, @Srikant already gave you the right answer since the rotation (or loadings) matrix contains eigenvectors arranged column-wise, so that you just have to multiply (using `%*%`) your vector or matrix of new data with e.g. `prcomp(X)$rotation`. Be careful, however, with any extra centering or scaling parameters that were applied when computing PCA EVs.

In R, you may also find useful the `predict()` function, see `?predict.prcomp`. BTW, you can check how projection of new data is implemented by simply entering:

```
getS3method("predict", "prcomp")
```

Answer (score 31):

Just to add to @chl's fantastic answer (+1), you can use a more lightweight solution:

```
# perform principal components analysis
pca <- prcomp(data) 

# project new data onto the PCA space
scale(newdata, pca$center, pca$scale) %*% pca$rotation
```

This is very useful if you do not want to save the entire `pca` object for projecting `newdata` onto the PCA space.

Answer (score 9):

In SVD, if A is an m x n matrix, the top k rows of the right singular matrix V, is a k-dimension representation of the original columns of A where k <= n

A = UΣV<sup>t</sup>
=> A<sup>t</sup> = VΣ<sup>t</sup>U<sup>t</sup> = VΣU<sup>t</sup> 
=> A<sup>t</sup>U = VΣU<sup>t</sup>U = VΣ  -----------(because U is orthogonal)
=> A<sup>t</sup>UΣ<sup>-1</sup>=VΣΣ<sup>-1</sup>=V

So $V = A^tUΣ$<sup>-1</sup>

The rows of A<sup>t</sup> or the columns of A map to the columns of V.
If the matrix of the new data on which to perform PCA for dimension reduction is Q, a q x n matrix, then use the formula to calculate $R = Q^tUΣ$<sup>-1</sup>, the result R is the desired result. R is an n by n matrix, and the top k rows of R (can be seen as a k by n matrix) is a new representation of Q's columns in the k-dimension space.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the eigenvectors (i.e., the principal components) should be arranged as columns.