# How to project a new vector onto PCA space when data is high-dimensional?

Tags: pca

**Branching off this question:** [How to project a new vector onto PCA space?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2592/287657)

Let's say our input matrix is of dimensionality, e.g. 90 samples and 10000 features.

If we run PCA on this high-dimensional data we get:

```
# Sudo Code in an R like language. 
data = read.csv("highdimdata.csv")
dimensions(data)                  # Returns 90 x 10000
result = pca(data)
dimensions(result.eiganvalues())  # Returns 90 x 1
dimensions(result.eiganvector())  # Returns 90 x 20
```

Note, that 20 here is arbitrary number of principal components. We can set this higher or lower. Of course, we cannot exceed min(samples, feature), i.e. min(90, 10000).

If we try to project a new sample:

```
newsample = read.csv("newsample.csv")
dimensions(newsample)          # Returns 1 x 10000
newsample_eiganv = (newsample %*% result.eiganvector())  // ISSUE HERE
```

**Issue:** Because of the dimensionality mismatch it is impossible to project new data onto the PCA space. Cannot project a vector of (1 x 10000) onto a matrix of (90 x 20).

There has to be a solution. People re-project new data all the time. What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like you might be feeding a data matrix to your PCA software that's the transpose of what it expects. If you have 90 samples and 10k features (i.e. 90 data points in a 10k dimensional space), then each eigenvector should have 10k dimensions. On an unrelated note, when projecting new points into the low dimensional space, don't forget to first subtract the mean of the training data.

Comment: Interesting, I am using snpgdsPCA( ), and given 90 SampleIDs and 10000 SNPs the output is an eigenvector of 90 x 20. Any idea why this might be @user20160? Note, when plotting the first two PCs the results look accurate, so I doubt the library isn't working properly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software you're using; you should check the documentation for how it expects data to be formatted. As I mentioned, it's likely the data matrix is transposed compared to what the software expects, meaning that samples are getting misinterpreted as dimensions and vice versa.

Comment: I do not think there is a transpose issue. Sklearn.decomposition.PCA( ) does the same thing. The eigenvector ends up being (Samples x Principal Components),  just like result of snpgdsPCA( ). Perhaps I am confusing what an eigenvector is?

Comment: Another other possibility is that you're misinterpreting the output as weights/eigenvectors when it's actually projections of the data points. In general, suppose you have $n$ points in $d$ dimensions and you ask for $k$ principal components. Then the weight matrix (containing eigenvectors of the covariance matrix) will have size $d \times k$ (or $k \times d$) and the projections (low dimensional representations of the training data) will have size $n \times k$ (or $k \times n$).

Comment: This is exactly what I was misinterpreting! Thank you!

Comment: If you are relatively new to PCA, study well first all examples when n>p (number of cases/observations is greater than the number of variables/features).  PCA is possible with n<p situation (which is less usual), but it is a bit "tupsy-turvy". Read then the threads here about PCA discussing the "n<p" instance.

Comment: How would I find the weight matrix? Others say: weights = pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_), however this would still not result in a d x k (or k x d) matrix. This is because pca.components_ is (n x k) and pca.explained_variance_ is (n x 1) or (k x 1).

Comment: To reiterate, I want to re-project new data onto the results of a previous PCA run. Would that still be possible when n < p? @ttnphns

Comment: Yes it will be possible. But you start with n>p case. Will you have issues then or not? It will help to see where is the misunderstanding.

Comment: Understood, I will do-so. @ttnphns Does this solution not work when n < p? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42046659/9100276